# How to fix that bug with drawing 3 balls on separate positions?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas

So, I'm drawing 3 balls on the top of screen. I'm using surfaceView. Here is the drawing code:

```
private void doDraw(Canvas c) 
{
    grid.Draw(c);
    nextBallsBar.Draw(c);
}
```

Grid:

```
public void Draw(Canvas c)
{
c.drawBitmap(Texture, 0, 0, null);
}
```

NextBallsBar:

```
public class NextBallsBar
{
private Bitmap ball1;
private Bitmap ball2;
private Bitmap ball3;

public void SetNextBalls(BallType[] ballTypes)
{
ball1 = BallTexturesProvider.GetBallTexture(ballTypes[0]);
ball2 = BallTexturesProvider.GetBallTexture(ballTypes[1]);
ball3 = BallTexturesProvider.GetBallTexture(ballTypes[2]);
}

public void Draw(Canvas c)
{
    //Point _position = new Point((int) (400 * GameView.scaleX), (int) (42 * GameView.scaleY));        
    c.drawBitmap(ball1, (int) 200, (int) (42 * GameView.scaleY), null);

//_position = new Point((int) (_position.x - 60 * GameView.scaleX), _position.y);
    c.drawBitmap(ball2, (int) 150, (int) (42 * GameView.scaleY), null);

    //_position = new Point((int) (_position.x - 60 * GameView.scaleX), _position.y);
    c.drawBitmap(ball3, (int) 100, (int) (42 * GameView.scaleY), null);
}
```

}

[image: problem]

There should be drawn only 3 balls separate from each other. Like on my WP7 version.

What's wrong ? Please, I hope you'll help me!

Comment: "That bug"? Is this a known issue?

Comment: This is the bug of MY code, I guess.

Comment: Could it be an error in BallTexturesProvider.GetBallTexture? If you draw only ball1, only ball2, and only ball3, does each of those draw exactly one ball?

Comment: Comment grid.Draw(c); and see if you just see 3 balls.

Comment: @Sana Only changes that background is disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not solve all your problems, but you should clear the screen before redrawing, using something like `c.drawColor(0xFF000000);` (to fill it with black). If you don't redraw the view, you will see the previous frame behind the current. 
Of course, if your grid texture cover the entire screen and don't use transparency, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!
My texture is concatenation of frames for animation. So, I drawing whole texture, not the first frame :(
Sorry